# pandas plot datetime groupby distribution

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm working with a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
User_ID    Datetime
01    2014-01-01 08:00:00
01    2014-01-02 09:00:00
02    2014-01-02 10:00:00
02    2014-01-03 11:00:00
03    2014-01-04 12:00:00
04    2014-01-04 13:00:00
05    2014-01-02 14:00:00
```

I don't care about the hour, I'd like to plot the frequency of Users/day/year. The expected df would be:

```
Datetime;count
2014-01-01;1
2014-01-02;3
2014-01-03;1
2014-01-04;2
```

So far I grouped the df by:

```
g = df.groupby['Datetime','User_ID']
```

but in this way I cannot group by the days only. I can have access to the days setting the 'Datetime' column as index of the df, and then `df.index.day`, but in this way again (working on all year dates), I can group only by days (from 1 to 31), and not in a sequence as `month.day`. Then I would like to plot the results as a distribution with `df.plot(kind='hist')`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the date trough `date` attribute, so you can do:

```
df.groupby(df['Datetime'].dt.date)['User_id'].count()
```

If it is possible there are multiple entries for one ID per date, you can use `nunique` instead of `count`